# TFS 2017 How to delete Build?

Tags: tfs

How can we delete a build in TFS 2017? I was able to do this in TFS 2015 and before, they switched to the new Azure DevOps / web site way of doing builds?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to delete the build definition?

Comment: no, build as i said, thanks...

Comment: Ok, see my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the page you are exist (the build summary) press on the build definition name (in the top left, near the current build number). then in the left tabs press on `History` tab. now hover with the mouse on the build name and click on the three dots `...`, you will see `Delete build` option.

Comment: you're welcome! I wanted to attached also a picture but I couldn't when I posted the answer... sorry!